# Auto-reload gets stuck during compilation

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I have no idea what's causing this. A few days ago I didn't have this problem but lately, whenever I edit any line of code, the auto-reload gets stuck during `Compiling...`:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 302 kB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
```

It't not terminating and I have to *kill* `ng` and restart the whole thing.

This happens after like 10 to 20 auto-reloads - at the beginning everything is working.

I already `rm -rf node_modules` - the classic way to fix `npm` issues apparently - and re-installed all modules but that didn't work.

Please let me know if I can give you any additional information.

**Update:**

I updated angular-cli to 7.0.6 and I still have the same problem. This issue seems to be present in all my projects.

---

#### (new) Environment

```
$ ng --version    
Angular CLI: 7.0.6
Node: 11.0.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.1.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, material, material-moment-adapter, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.6
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.6
@angular/cli                      7.0.6
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.19
@angular/language-service         <error>
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.6
@schematics/angular               7.0.6
@schematics/update                0.10.6
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.19.1
```

#### (old) Environment

```
$ ng --version
Angular CLI: 6.2.2
Node: 11.0.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.8.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.8.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.8.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.8.2
@angular-devkit/core               0.8.2
@angular-devkit/schematics         0.8.2
@angular/cdk                       6.4.7
@angular/cli                       6.2.2
@angular/flex-layout               6.0.0-beta.18
@angular/material                  6.4.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   6.4.7
@ngtools/webpack                   6.2.2
@schematics/angular                0.8.2
@schematics/update                 0.8.2
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         2.9.2
webpack                            4.19.0
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Has _that_ been updated? Maybe it's locking or writing to a file ng is trying to do something to?

Comment: @msanford I am using WebStorm 2017.2 - I didn't update my IDE though.

Comment: I wonder if dropping to a lower version of node would help.

Comment: @R.Richards I tried the oppositeand updated to v7.1.0 but it's still the same. The problem seems to occur in *all* my projects and it's driving me crazy by now ..

Comment: You're on node 11. I was thinking if you dropped to node 8, or 10, you might have better luck. My experience has been that being on the "latest features" version of node isn't always a good idea. There always seems to be issues, like what you are having. Since your issues are happening with all you projects now, node could be the culprit.

Comment: @R.Richards I didn't realize what pain it can be to actually downgrade node but .. I'm now at v10 and I'll use that for today - let's see if it works. In any case thanks for your help.

Comment: @R.Richards Seems like that was it. 1 hour of programming - still no getting stuck.

Comment: That is great! I hope that continues to work for you.

Comment: @R.Richards :D Me too.. Thanks for your help. If you want to provide an answer I'm going to accept it. I'll leave my question open in case people stumble upon it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using node 11.0.0, we can see that in the version output you provided.

If you downgraded to node 8.13.0, or 10.13.0 (current LTS when writing this), you might have better luck.

My experience has been that being on the *Latest Features* version of node isn't always a good idea. There sometimes seems to be little issues, like what you are having. I used to always like to be on the latest and greatest when it came to node, but I found it can cause problems.

Since your issues are happening with *all* your projects now, node could be the culprit.

Comment: I'm now on 10.13.0 which seems to work so far. Thanks :)