# angular 7 is blocked when save

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-cli-v7

I'm with version 7 of angular and from time to time, the compiler is "stuck" and I have to close the terminal and reopen it (no matter time you expect).

Do you know if it has a solution? I have already reinstalled angular cleaning cache and other

When you start everything ok, the page loads correctly and works:
[image]

But when doing some saved and that is recompile automatically as it should, I save again and this happens: (no error, but the "compiling..." message does not appear )
[image]

The "solution" is to close the console and reopen it, but it is not very optimal, this happens from the vscode terminal and also with the normal terminal, I have already ruled out that the vscode terminal is the problem

The port also tried to change it from 4200 to another ... :(

I do not know what's wrong, All code is available in https://github.com/DanielOrtegaConesa/Musicfy/tree/master/client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-reload gets stuck during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452130/auto-reload-gets-stuck-during-compilation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue due to node version problem
go back to older version of your node js

Reported error on angular CLI repo on git hub

## 12904

Comment: happens to me with V6 and always that is the problem . hope it helps